# What classloader does "new" use, and how do i change it?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm developing a simple Plugin System and I basically want to control which classloader loads a class on a `new` instruction.
For instance I have a jar with my main program, and I distribute a class `Foo.class` in a extra packaged jar called `Bar.jar`.

I see three different possibilities to include the jar in my main program:

1. package `Bar.jar` with my main jar to include it in the classpath. This is obviously not feasible for a plugin system
2. Load the class `Foo` with an URL ClassLoader pointing to the jar. This would be too unfamiliar with the default java programmer to load classes manually via its name
3. Set a custom Classloader as the System-classloader via the `-Djava.system.class.loader` argument. But I dont really want to force the user to start his application with extra arguments.

Is there another way? Maybe something to register a Custom classloader for specific classes? or change the Classloader `new` uses at Runtime? Setting the `ContextClassLoader` of the `Thread` does not work.

Comment: Looks like you need [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi).

Comment: The classloader is connected to a class, not to the `new` keyword. Leave the `new` keyword out of this, it's never done you any harm.

Comment: Do you really need to control how `new` loads a class? Thinking of a plugin system how did you define the way to find/reference the jar(s) with pluggable classes in general if you don't want to add all jars to the classpath when starting the program? I suppose this might bring up some hints on how to instantiate pluggable classes...

Comment: @BoristheSpider after spending weeks trying to wrap my head around OSGi and the complete lack of Documentations/Tutorials thereof I decided to implement it myself, because it seems way simpler

Comment: @jCoder of course, and i already implemented a way to load and instantiate Plugin classes with interfaces, and it works really well. This is just another way to modularize programs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you load a class, the classes it refers to use the same class loader as it.  This means to control the class loader used implicitly, you can to use a different class loader for the one which starts it all. e.g. Your first Runnable.

```
class A {
    B b = new B();
```

The `new B` will chose the ClassLoader used for A (or a parent)

Setting the context class loader works for dynamic lookups like `Class.forName(name);` is the same as `Class.forName(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), name);`

Once a class is loaded it will always use the same classes it depends on.  It's not possible to swap different classes based on say a thread context.  This means a class with a very specific classloader can use classes which are more generally used (e.g. as the general class is from a parent), however a more general used class cannot use a more specific class loader it is not aware of. i.e. ClassLoaders are not aware of their children.

One reason for this is that threads share memory.  This means you can't say that when A creates a new B in one thread it will be different to another thread as the A instance could be accessed by either thread.